# How to access nested JSON array data with angular, filtered by array parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

Using info returned from an API in the form of JSON, I am trying to manipulate the following data:

```
"results": [
    {
        "url": "etcetc",
        "id": 1,
        "user": {
            "url": "etcetc",
            "id": 2,
            "email": "email@example.com",
            "username": "example",
            "first_name": "mister",
            "last_name": "sample"
        },
        "data1": "String",
        "data2": 10,
        "data3": 6,
        "data4": 12000,
        "data5": 0.3333333333333333
    }
```

so there are several objects returned under "results", and each object has its own set of data1-5.  Using Angular, what is the best way to search for the object with the highest data5, and return the rest of the info for that particular object? So I'd print out data1-5 for the array object with the highest data5 value, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have an object, not JSON, or parse the JSON into an object, you can use `Array.reduce`

```
var max = obj.results.reduce(function(a,b) {
    return a.data5 > b.data5 ? a : b;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/kx1o4a0b/)

---

ES2015 version

```
var max = obj.results.reduce( (a, b) => a.data5 > b.data5 ? a : b );
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for-each loop is all you need:

```
highest = results[0]  // seed highest with the first element

results.forEach(function(el) {
  if (el['data5'] > highest['data5'])
    highest = el
})
```